# PHP | WordPress | Multiple navigation menus with similar args

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, menu, range

I'm building a large corporate site, the navigation (on desktop) contains 6 columns containing 6 different menus. I have everything working, my concern is the verbose code. There is lots of repetition. I'm adding this six times:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'nav-1',
    'depth' => 1,
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'col-md px-0 mb-5',
    'container_id' => 'nav-1',
    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav h5',
    'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
);
```

Is there a way of saving the constant args as a variable and then just sequentially changing the number after `nav-`?

Comment: How about to define an ID such as $id=1; then use 'nav-'.$id instead of 'nav-1'. will this be possible?

Comment: @ildflueIt sort of, but I'd need 6 of them, so I'd need the PHP to generate 6 versions of the array, each time changing the id to the next sequential number until it reaches 6. So you're right it does need a variable, but it needs to use PHP to be a range or something like that, which I can't suss out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to have? or something like this?

```
   for($id=1; $id<=6; $id++) {
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'nav-' . $id,
            'depth' => 1,
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'col-md px-0 mb-5',
            'container_id' => 'nav-' .  $id,
            'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav h5',
            'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this kinda solution

```
function op_wp_nav_menu( $which_nav ) {
    $which_nav = absint( $which_nav );
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => "nav-{$which_nav}",
        'depth' => 1,
        'container' => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'col-md px-0 mb-5',
        'container_id' => "nav-{$which_nav}",
        'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav h5',
        'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
    ) );
}
op_wp_nav_menu( 1 );
op_wp_nav_menu( 2 );
..
op_wp_nav_menu( 6 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ildflueIt for pointing me in the right direction and making me think. I've ended up doing this:

```
$menus = get_registered_nav_menus();
foreach ( $menus as $location => $description ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => $location,
       'depth' => 1,
       'container' => 'div',
       'container_class' => 'col-md px-0 mb-5',
       'container_id' => $location,
       'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav h5',
       'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
       'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
    );
}
```

Thanks also to @obiPlabon I liked the angle.